# What exactly is $\lfloor -0.5 \rceil $?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose $g(x) = \lfloor x \rceil$ converts a real number $x$ into its nearest integer.

I know

- $g(0.4) = 0$
- $g(0.6) = 1$

But what are those?

- $g(0.5) = ?$
- $g(-0.5) = ?$

Comment: You recieved 6 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 4):

"The nearest integer" to $0.5$ does not exist.

---

In other words, the sentence

> Suppose $g(x) = \lfloor x \rceil$ converts a real number $x$ into its
>   nearest integer.

Does not provide enough information to determine what $g(0.5)$ is equal to.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to asking

> The function $1/x$ converts a real number into its reciprocal; what is $1/0$?

Unless you somehow define the reciprocal of zero, the function is not defined at it.

Similarly, your function is not defined at points $x=n+1/2$, where $n$ is integer.

There are many ways to extend it, but each of them is somewhat arbitrary.

1. ties to $0$; in this case $\lfloor 1/2\rceil=0$, $\lfloor -1/2\rceil=0$, $\lfloor 3/2=1$, $\lfloor-3/2\rfloor=-1$
2. ties to $\infty$; in this case $\lfloor 1/2\rceil=1$, $\lfloor -1/2\rceil=0$, $\lfloor 3/2=2$, $\lfloor-3/2\rfloor=-1$
3. ties to $-\infty$: in this case $\lfloor 1/2\rceil=0$, $\lfloor -1/2\rceil=-1$, $\lfloor 3/2=1$, $\lfloor-3/2\rfloor=-2$
4. ties to even: in this case $\lfloor 1/2\rceil=0$, $\lfloor -1/2\rceil=0$, $\lfloor 3/2\rceil=2$ and $\lfloor -3/2\rceil=-2$

Answer (score 0):

"Nearest integer" is not defined here, and so $g(0.5)$ is not defined - if we are simply rounding to the nearest integer convention sometimes states that you round up if you are halfway between two integers, but this is quite arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Take the range of 
$$
0 \le \left\{ x \right\} = x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  < 1
$$
and divide it in discrete tens 
$$
\left( {0,{1 \over {10}},{2 \over {10}}, \cdots ,{9 \over {10}}} \right)
$$

There are ten divisions, and to make the partition "equilibrated"
we define 
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x < {1 \over 2}\quad  \to \quad \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  \hfill \cr 
  {1 \over 2} \le x < 1\quad  \to \quad \left\lceil x \right\rceil  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which is the standard rounding adopted in economics and engineering.

That translates to:
$$
{\rm Round}(x) = \left\lfloor {x + {1 \over 2}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {2\left\{ x \right\}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {2x} \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor 
$$
which in particular gives
$$
{\rm Round}\left( { - 1/2} \right) = 0,\quad {\rm Round}\left( 0 \right) = 0,\quad {\rm Round}\left( {1/2} \right) = 1
$$